# Confused about oAuth, creating secure API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

How do I secure my API when I want an app to be able to retrieve app-specific information without a user logged in and when I have an OAuth provider for another section of my API? Can I use the client app's OAuth credentials to hit the API without a user logged in?

I have create an OAuth provider and client using doorkeeper following  [railscasts 353](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper). I can successfully authenticate a user to my provider app and make requests on behalf of the user to my provider API.

However, a portion of the API is user independent, meaning that the information returned from the API is not specific for a user and therefore a user *should* not have to be logged in. For example, assume an ecommerce site and items and prices are stored on the provider for multiple clients. I want a client app to be able to securely retrieve the items/prices associated the retrieving app without a user having to be logged in. So if you went to example.com the items would be displayed even if a user is logged in via OAuth.

I have only be able to retrieve this information via OAuth when a user has logged in through OAuth (creating an access_token). Is there a way to use OAuth without having a user present (I've been trying to read about 2-legged OAuth and if that is an appropriate solution)? Or do I need to use Api keys (or Http Basic Auth) for the application to retrieve the application specific data?

If OAuth is not the right solution because I do not have a user present, could/should I use HTTP Basic Auth over SSL and use the client site's OAuth secret key as the API key for the basic auth username?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to authenticate your client apps in you API (without requiring a user specifically) use the [Client Credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)